# Zurb Foundation 5 - Top Bar - Collapses on small browser window but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

Having lifted the code from the documentation page

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name"> 
[etc...]
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

The ensuing result is that collapsing a *browser desktop window* generates the menu icon and active sub-item links.

It collapses as expected in Chrome normal desktop mode... however when accessing Chrome's developer tools **all** mobile renderings are **not** generating the menu icon (and neither, obviously the sub-items).

*Various issues verified... Loading all foundation javascripts at the end of the body tag does not change behaviour.  Removing files with custom css classes for mobile instances which are loaded after foundation.css does not alter behaviour. No application code, aside from robots.txt, calls `user-agent`.*

The following may be relevant, but I believe it came with the base code:

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:40.063em)/";
  width: 58.75em; }
```

So the menu is being generated on small desktop screens but not on mobile ones.

How can this be fixed? Is there a foundation configuration that somehow disables this logic for mobile?

Comment: Have you tested on an actual mobile device? Or are you just using the Chrome dev tools to emulate a mobile screen?

Would be interested to see a link to better troubleshoot, since there's a few different things that could be happening. In my experience, things like this are typically a result of missing an ending `div` tag or having some end tag nested inside something it's not supposed to be.

Comment: Yes I have tested with a mobile browser (iOS 4  and iOS5 Android 4.2.2) and am getting the same result.  staging.ride4.me  is one link you can use

Comment: I always use Tab Bar with menus, but it looks like in the docs, it's loading in the below order:

`<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
  <script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
  <!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->

  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
`

Maybe try this instead.

Comment: checking the generated source `Foundation Responsive Library` is loading before all the various js components (penultimate line).  I also tried placing the js calls at end of body, as stated above. No dice.  Besides why would it work for desktop re-sizing and **not** for mobile browsers?

Comment: Well I'm getting somewhere with the drop down menu idea.  That was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the expected answer.  And a kludge to boot.  But I still fail to pinpoint why the toggling is **not** occurring (while in other instances proper styles are being applied to `small` viewports with foundation's css.)

Essentially swap out one side with a [dropdown](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html), recreating the menu.

Soooo... this being a rails application, using in conjunction with the [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser) (condition `if browser`) and [font awesome gem](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) for a quicker route to generating the hamburger icon, the following does the trick, er... kludge.

```
<!-- Right Nav Section -->
<ul class="right">
<% if browser.mobile? %>
  <li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="#menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li class="active"> [etc.][etc.]
```